# HiveQL : use SELECT in clause WHERE

Tags: hive, hiveql

Is there a way to do this in HiveQL :

```
SELECT ......    

from
        default.thm_renta_produits_jour rpj
      WHERE
          rpj.co_societe = '${hiveconf:in_co_societe}'
      AND rpj.dt_jour >= (SELECT MIN(dt_jour) FROM default.calendrier WHERE co_an_semaine = '${hiveconf:in_co_an_sem}')
```

Because when i do this, i get this error :

```
FAILED: ParseException line 51:26 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'MIN' '(' in expression specification
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hive does not support sub queries in where clause it supports [sub queries in from clause](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries) only.

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not support sub queries in the `WHERE` clause. Perhaps you can work around this by moving your sub query to a `JOIN` clause like so:

```
SELECT 
    rpj.*
FROM
    default.thm_renta_produits_jour rpj
JOIN
   (   SELECT MIN(dt_jour) AS min_dt_jour 
       FROM default.calendrier 
       WHERE co_an_semaine = '${hiveconf:in_co_an_sem}'
   ) m
WHERE
    rpj.co_societe = '${hiveconf:in_co_societe}'
    AND rpj.dt_jour >= m.min_dt_jour;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but the previous answers are now outdated. Newer versions of Hive (0.13+) support subqueries of where clauses, so your query should run.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause